# Scatter plot size too small with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data for all car models, close to 300 model details. I am trying to plot all of them in a scatter plot sales over month and I am able to do that with `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(data=cars,aes(x=sales,y=accidents))+
 geom_point()+
 facet_wrap(~model)
```

But the graph size is too small and difficult to visualize. Is there a way to increase the graph size and better visual?

Comment: Am I correct that you have nearly 300 different car models?  The `facet_wrap` is generating nearly 300 facets?  The only reasonable way to get a usable image for this is to create a very large canvas in either `ggsave` or another `dev`.  I would suggest reducing the number of facets, perhaps `facet_wrap( ~ make)` would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

it is important that you put a reproducible code to know what's your problem.

Maybe you could resize the output image using:

```
png(file="name_of_img_save.png",width=3300 ,height=2000,res=150)
ggplot(data=cars,aes(x=sales,y=accidents))+ geom_point()+facet_wrap(~model)
dev.off()
```

Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for visualization you should probably try the `manipulate` package for RStudio. You can adapt it easily to have axis controls.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551906-Interactive-Plotting-with-Manipulate